# .NET 8 ResourceFile not working when using period in folder name

Tags: c#, .net-8.0

I want to use a ResourceFile within a folder with a period in the foldername ("R4.3")
This was working in .NET Framework 4.8
But now we upgraded to .NET 8, and now it's not working anymore.
I tried adding a folder with a underscore (R4_3) and that does work.
But I'm hoping for another solution, because otherwise I have to rename a lot of folders.

For an example see:
See https://github.com/janssenr/ResourceFile

Comment: I think you'll have to rename the folders:  github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4382

Answer (score 11):

It's not the period/dot that is causing the issue, but the numeric only segment.

That is because the folders will be part of the namespace of the class generated in the `.designer.cs` file, and a namespace cannot have a numeric only segment.

`ConsoleApp1.SF.R4.3.OUT.Internal` is not a valid namespace.

Even the `.resources` file built in the `obj\Debug\net8.0` folder has that numeric segment replaced in it's name. Notice that `.3.` became `._3.`.

[image]

---

In case renaming those folders is not an option, then you can set the `CustomToolNamespace` of the affected `.resx` file(s) to a valid namespace; e.g. that `ConsoleApp1.SF.R4._3.OUT.Internal` or any other valid one.

[image]

This gives below in your `.csproj` file. Notice the `<CustomToolNamespace>ConsoleApp1.SF.R4._3.OUT.Internal</CustomToolNamespace>`.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Update="SF\R4.3\OUT\Internal\ResourceFile.Designer.cs">
    <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
    <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
    <DependentUpon>ResourceFile.resx</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
  <Compile Update="SF\R4_3\OUT\Internal\ResourceFile.Designer.cs">
    <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
    <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
    <DependentUpon>ResourceFile.resx</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <Resource Include="SF\R4.3\OUT\Internal\ResourceFile.resx">
   <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
    <CustomToolNamespace>ConsoleApp1.SF.R4._3.OUT.Internal</CustomToolNamespace>
    <LastGenOutput>ResourceFile.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
  </Resource>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Update="SF\R4_3\OUT\Internal\ResourceFile.resx">
    <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
    <LastGenOutput>ResourceFile.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
  </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

---

Instead of having to rename a lot of folders, you end up with a namespace change/refactoring, which might be easier to accomplish.

That code fragment from within your mentioned GitHub repo then becomes

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xslt = SF.R4._3.OUT.Internal.ResourceFile.Product;
        }
    }
}
```

Result in Visual Studio

[image]